# Filtering a table to find a single row in R with an if_else or case_when statement

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I need to filter my data to select a single row that is the latest `Date`.
When there are two rows with the latest dates, I then need to filter based on the `test` result:

If the `max(test) >= 60` I want to select the row with the `min(test)`, `else` I want to select the row with `max(test)`

```r
library(dplyr)
Date= c("2020/04/16", "2020-07-01", "2020-07-01")
ID= c(12,12,12)
test= rnorm(3, mean=150, sd=60)
data= data.frame(ID, Date, test)
data$Date = lubridate::ymd(data$Date)
```

I have attempted the following

```
data = data%>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))%>%
  filter(if_else(max(test) >= 60, test == min(test), test == max(test)))
```

and

```
data = data%>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))%>%
  filter(test == if_else(max(test) >= 60, test == min(test), test == max(test)))
```

and

```
data1 = data%>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))%>%
  if_else(max(test) >= 60, filter(test == min(test)), filter(test == max(test)))
```

None of these work, though logically I think they should. I get errors for all of them.

<sup>Created on 2020-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your approach use `if`/`else` since this is a scalar comparison.

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>%
  filter(if(max(test) >= 60) test == min(test) else test == max(test))

#  ID       Date     test
#1 12 2020-07-01 78.43785
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. Could you explain scalar comparisons

Comment: `max(test) >= 60` returns output of length 1 which is scalar. `if_else` expects an input vector.